Is it legal to send a modified version of a GPL 3.0 Licensed Software to only one person?
I want to modify something licensed under the GPL 3.0 License and send it to only one person. This person does not distribute the modified version any further. The source code of the modified version won't be published.
Is this against the license? If no, would it be against the license if the person paid for it?
I don't want to get into legal troubles with the authors of the original software, and I like their product so I don't want to do things with it that are against its license.

Do note that you are required to either supply the source together with that modified version (so that this person could redistribute or publish it), or with a written, binding agreement that you will provide the source to anyone who gets their hands on that modified version, i.e. if "this person does not distribute the modified version any further" somehow turns out to be false. See GPLv3 section 6 which exhaustively lists your options for providing the source, of which you must pick at least one.

If it weren't, a new Linux distribution could never sell its first copy ;-)

Does this GPL FAQ answer your question: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLRequireSourcePostedPublic


The source code of the modified version won't be published. Is this against the license?

That depends what you mean.
If you mean "you won't publish the source anywhere public", that's fine. The GPL requirement is only ever to give the source to someone who has a copy of the covered work.
If you mean "you won't give the source to the one other person if they ask for it", that's not fine.

would it be against the license if the person paid for it?

That is fine; quoting from the license (Section 4):
"You may charge any price or no price for each copy that you convey"
For avoidance of doubt:

This person does not distribute the modified version any further.

You cannot enforce this. You can ask them not to, but they are within their rights to ignore your request.

I wouldn't say that "You can ask them not to" is accurate - you are required to explicitly give them permission to do so, by notifying that you are giving them this software under the GPL licence which permits that, and if you would "ask them not to" in a legally binding way in a separate contract, then you would be violating the GPL conditions ("You may not impose any further restrictions on the exercise of the rights granted or affirmed under this License. ") and you would not have the right to distribute the software with these extra limits and you would be violating copyright by doing so.

@Peteris Separate contracts restricting GPL rights is not a settled question; see Bradley Kuhn's article: "Debates continue, even today, in copyleft expert circles, whether this model itself violates GPL."

That article (and the whole debate) seems to be about consequences for future business deals, but, quoting the article "As we understand it, this contract clearly states that the terms do not intend to contradict any rights to copy, modify, redistribute and/or reinstall the software" - i.e. the discussed model does not restrict these rights for the version provided.

I think this answer missing the important point that the person receiving the software must agree to the GPL, i.e.: if it gives away the compiled code, it must also offer to give away the source code. I think it would be unfair to ask the original author to provide the source code then.

@Peteris (first comment) I think it would be quite a stretch to argue that "in a legally binding way in a separate contract" counts as asking.

When you send your modified copy to ONE person you must follow the GPL requirements, or you commit copyright infringement. You have the choice: Make a promise to anybody in the world to send them the source code on request. Or send the modified software including the modified source code to the one person.
If you send the modified software to one person, there is no requirement to tell the world about it. The receiver can. And they can tell everyone to ask you for the source code. If they don't do that, and nobody knows what you did, then nobody will ask you for the source code. And that is legal.

"And they can tell everyone to ask you for the source code." This bit isn't correct - my requirements end once I've given the source code to a second person. If they give the binary to a third person, the second person is responsible for distributing the source, not me. If the third person doesn't have the binary, they have no right to the source. (Reference: GPL v3 section 6)

"Or send the modified software including the modified source code to the one person." This bit is not fully correct. The author of the software has the right to just offer the Corresponding Source to the recipient(s) of the binaries by putting it on an FTP server or the like. (see GPL v3 Section 6d).
There is no need to make sure that every recipient of the binary also has a copy of the source code (see here ), recipients just need easy access if they want the source code.

"Make a promise to anybody in the world to send them the source code on request. Or send the modified software including the modified source code to the one person." You're thinking GPLv2. This question is about GPLv3, so it is not true. Refer to the 5 methods in Section 6. Your first statement is now limited to "occasionally and noncommercially" under 6c, unless it's embedded, 6b.

If every recipient of the modified executable was personally aware of a way that they could get the modified source code (e.g. "Ask Bob for it"), I would think that would satisfy the requirement.

@supercat It does not. GPLv2 and v3 both specify software must be accompanied by a written offer, when that method is used.
